# grunt: problems npm with proxy

Tags: node.js, proxy, npm

I am having problems with the proxy but I think it is ok about the configuration. It is when I just executing `npm install`.

my error in console is:

[image]

my file npm-debug.log tells me:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'grunt-contrib-concat',
1 verbose cli   '--dev-save',
1 verbose cli   '--global' ]
2 info using npm@2.11.3
3 info using node@v0.12.7
4 verbose install initial load of C:\Users\dmora\AppData\Roaming\npm\package.json
5 verbose readDependencies loading dependencies from C:\Users\dmora\AppData\Roaming\npm\package.json
6 silly cache add args [ 'grunt-contrib-concat', null ]
7 verbose cache add spec grunt-contrib-concat
8 silly cache add parsed spec { raw: 'grunt-contrib-concat',
8 silly cache add   scope: null,
8 silly cache add   name: 'grunt-contrib-concat',
8 silly cache add   rawSpec: '',
8 silly cache add   spec: '*',
8 silly cache add   type: 'range' }
9 silly addNamed grunt-contrib-concat@*
10 verbose addNamed "*" is a valid semver range for grunt-contrib-concat
11 silly addNameRange { name: 'grunt-contrib-concat', range: '*', hasData: false }
12 silly mapToRegistry name grunt-contrib-concat
13 silly mapToRegistry using default registry
14 silly mapToRegistry registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
15 silly mapToRegistry uri http://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-concat
16 verbose addNameRange registry:http://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-concat not in flight; fetching
17 verbose request uri http://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-concat
18 verbose request no auth needed
19 info attempt registry request try #1 at 17:48:55
20 verbose request id 5852220cb81144b0
21 http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-concat
22 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
23 info attempt registry request try #2 at 17:49:06
24 http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-concat
25 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
26 info attempt registry request try #3 at 17:50:07
27 http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-concat
28 verbose stack Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
28 verbose stack     at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
28 verbose stack     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1010:19)
29 verbose cwd D:\_PROYECTOS\Serunet CK.Client\SeruWeb\SN.CK.Front\Serunet.CK.Client.Web.Tests.ShowInBrowse
30 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
31 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "grunt-contrib-concat" "--dev-save" "--global"
32 error node v0.12.7
33 error npm  v2.11.3
34 error code ECONNREFUSED
35 error errno ECONNREFUSED
36 error syscall connect
37 error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
37 error     at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
37 error     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1010:19)
37 error  { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
37 error   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
37 error   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
37 error   syscall: 'connect' }
38 error If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
38 error 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
39 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Finally I insert my .npmrc file:

```
proxy=http://Domain\user:password@xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/ 
https-proxy=http://Domain\user:password@xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/

registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/

strict-ssl = false
ca = null
```

.npmrc file is in directory: `c:\users\myuser\.npmrc`

I think everything is correct but it is giving me that errors.

What is wrong in configuration?

Comment: Try removing the Domain from the proxy. Leave just the username and password. That has always worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was problem of the proxy of that corporation. Where I am now it is working fine. For me it is resolved.